If $xf(x)$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ then $f(x) \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}).$ (Schwartz Space)
Is it true that if $xf(x)$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ then $f(x) \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$?
I thought maybe it is, since that would have to "force" $f(x)$ to decay, but I'm not sure. Could someone give me a hint?

Can you precise $S$

@EDX It's the Schwartz Space, that is, $|x^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}f| < \infty$ for all $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}_{>=0}$

I have nothing against Cameron's answer, but it does feel a bit like cheating, as in the counterexample-ness seems to come moreso from the behaviour at $0$ rather than the one at infinity... You should probably ask at the very least that $f$ be continuous at least at $0$ to get either more interesting counterexamples or on the contrary a positive answer.

If $f$ is assumed to be smooth, then the answer is affirmative. Otherwise, Cameron's answer or a similar construction would work to produce a counter-example.

@SangchulLee Sir, this is my case. How to prove that? Can you give me a hint?

@Gaumap, As a hint, note that we always have $$\sup_{|x|\leq 2024}|x^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}f|<\infty$$ for any indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$, simply due to the smoothness of $f$. This means that all you have to worry about is how $|x^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}f|$ behaves for large $x$. This shouldn't be hard using the condition $xf \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

No, consider $x^{-1} e^{-x^2}$.
